# Python Regex match and search doesnt work

Tags: python, regex

Suppose i have this regex.

```
[0-9 ]{5,7}
```

I am using python.

```
import re
re.search(r'[0-9 ]{5,7}', '1123124213')
```

This will return a positive for this.

However, if i were to use

```
re.match(r'[0-9 ]{5,7}', '1123124213')
```

However, my string is usually something like:

```
I am going home tonight call me at 21314123
```

Tokenization does not work either. How do i resolve this?

I would like to match this.

```
I am going home tonight call me at 21314
```

but not

```
I am going home tonight call me at 21314123
```

However, if i were to use regex i would be able to search both `21314` and `21314123`

Basically i have a list of strings containing such strings.

```
I am going home tonight call me at 213123 
I am going home tonight call me at 21313 
I am going home tonight call me at 2131 
I am going home tonight call me at 21314213123 
I am going home tonight call me at 21314
```

and i would like to use regex/ any methods to extract those that contain

```
I am going home tonight call me at 21314
```

Comment: Resolve what? Any errors?

Comment: @ase could you explain the logic behind the above?

Comment: @aceminer - so you want to capture number with length of 5-7 only? Other should be rejected?

Comment: @vrajs5 yes that is right

Answer (score 2):

`re.search` will find your pattern anywhere in the string, while `re.match` will only find it at the beginning.  So, for your example string, `re.match` won't return a value.